# How to extract a specific item from a array of Typescript objects?

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript, can you help me with this-

I have an array of objects, -

```
[{Name: a,
  Age: 1
 },
 {Name: b,
  Age: 2
 }
]
```

I want an array which should be - [a, b]

I tried with the following but I am not getting the expected result-

```
for (int i=0; i< treeData.length; i++) {
    finalArray.push(treeData[i][0]);
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance..

Comment: `finalArray.push(treeData[i].Name)`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is invalid syntax:

```
for (int i=0; i< treeData.length; i++) {
```

`int` is not a valid typescript type, and if it was, that is not the right syntax to use it. You need to create a variable there, which will be implicitly typed from its initial value.

```
for (let i=0; i< treeData.length; i++) {
```

---

Secondly, here:

```
finalArray.push(treeData[i][0]);
```

You have an array of objects. You are trying to index the array with an integer `i`, which is fine. But then you are trying to index the objects in that array with another integer `0`, which is not valid. Objects are indexed by the *name* of their keys, not the index of their keys.

That means you need to ask each object for the `Name` property.

```
finalArray.push(treeData[i].Name);
```

---

Putting that all together looks like this:

```
const treeData = [
    { Name: "a", Age: 1 },
    { Name: "b", Age: 2 },
]

const finalArray: string[] = []

for (let i=0; i< treeData.length; i++) {
    finalArray.push(treeData[i].Name);
}
console.log(finalArray); // ['a', 'b']
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBTRARAhlNMC8MDaAsAFAykwDeMAcmgLaIBcMARGswDQwCCA5ozAEYYAX3bEyFanX7MARh258mAJhFiiAXWLFQkWADMAlmDQAbLvHhoAnk2jxjPPBpz4tRYvpDwYAClOIsIbYAAwA3DCGADxwSKgYaAB0AWA8UAAWEYYA1NkAlBTiZEYm5pY2iQAOAK4Q6b4IyOiYeIYaiTT0eWHEwjrgECABySA8viVmFlbW3UA)

---

Although, this is a lot more code than you need. It's best to avoid indexed loops in favor of iterating over the array elements.

In this case if you want to derive a value from each element of an array. That's called [a `map` operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const treeData = [
    { Name: "a", Age: 1 },
    { Name: "b", Age: 2 },
]

const finalArray = treeData.map(obj => obj.Name)

console.log(finalArray); // ['a', 'b']
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUnusedLocals=true&noImplicitOverride=true&ssl=8&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBTRARAhlNMC8MDaAsAFAykwDeMAcmgLaIBcMARGswDQwCCA5ozAEYYAX3bEyFanX7MARh258mAJhFiiAXWLFQkWADMAlmDQAbLvHhoAnjjhJUGNADpaaAA4AKELIBWOAD4YH19nGnoASm0iXQgQU0RnUxAeTyMTc0sbCIBuGAB6fPwAcjRizmLZYo0gA)

Answer (score 1):

you can use map here:

documentation to map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
let treeData = [
    { Name: "a", Age: 1 },
    { Name: "b", Age: 2 },
]

var finalArray = treeData.map(item => item.Name)
console.log(finalArray) // ['a', 'b']
```